Can UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate notify when user save file
Is there a UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate callback to detect when user save file on the phone, on cloud or everywhere else ?
I can see didEndSendingToApplication to detect when a file is sent to an other app. But nothing for "Save to Device" inside the options menu.
I'm building an app with a download feature where when a file is download we display a preview and we let user decide if he want download or not. We are a bit blocked because on the preview we can't detect download events.
